dynamic IP keeps coming back
We've got a ghost IP address that keeps coming back. 10.203.32.245 has type dynamic but dhcpd is not running, I cant find anything on the machine dhcp although I dont know much about dhcp.
After deleting the IP with ip addr del 10.203.... dev ens33 it appears again after a while, so dhcp must be running somewhere. What do I need to check?


First you can check if DHCP is present with:
sudo dhclient -v

If you dont want that DHCP gives you an IP address then you need to configure your network manually. Create a file /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
touch /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

Then put your configuration into it.
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens33:
            addresses:
            - 10.203.32.xxx/24
            dhcp4: false
            routes:
            - to: default
              via: 10.203.32.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 1.1.1.1
                - 8.8.8.8
                search:
                - your.domain.com

Adjust IP address and the gateway address to your needs.

strange. setting dhcp4 to "false or no" and after netplan apply then dhclient -v still says dhcp is on

Since you did not stop the dhcp service it is still running.
